# Ansible "Indirect inventory" (sort of)

Tags: windows, ansible

I am quite new to Ansible, and I wonder if someone save me some feeling my way in the darkness, and share what is the best way to do the following.

I have several cloud environments with windows (mostly) windows hosts that I want to manage with Ansible. The thing is, that my Ansible server is outside these environments and I can't WinRM directly to the various Windows hosts (security, you know...) So what I would like to do is to add a Linux host to each cloud environment and use these hosts as kind of a proxy: I will access them from the Ansible server and use the psexec module to access the Windows server.

My problem though is that if I do that then my Ansible inventory will include only the Linux "Proxies" and I will not be able to categorize the Windows servers in to policy groups.

So again, can anyone share how to properly handle this? I guess I just need some way to create an inventory-like structure of of the windows severs and associate it with the appropriate "Proxy" hosts.

Many thanks,

Oren

Comment: This looks on topic: https://serverfault.com/questions/734833/how-do-i-configure-a-winrm-jump-host-for-use-with-ansible

Comment: Thanks @larsks . Using the ansible_host parameter actually solves my problem. I have a question though, can I somehow define it once per a group of hosts, instead of again and again for each host?